# Every time a post is published, remove all the other published posts

Tags: wordpress

**The problem**: Due to RSS conversion to posts related issues, I want to have just one blog post published in the backend of the my blog page. I am aware that I can display only the last blog post but is not what I want.

Is there a function or a plugin that could delete/remove permanently all other posts that are already published every time I publish a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I hope it helps someone with the same question:

```
function delete_all_posts_less_the_first() {
    $posts_less_the_first = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'offset' => '1') );

    foreach ( $posts_less_the_first as $post_less_the_first ) {
        // Delete all posts less the first.
        wp_delete_post( $post_less_the_first->ID, true); // Set to False if you want to send them to Trash.
    } 
}
add_action( 'init', 'delete_all_posts_less_the_first' );
```